# Multiple movie clips in ScrollPane

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am loading multiple movie clips into a scrollpaneContainer mc and setting the source of my scrollpane to be the scrollpaneContainer.

Problem is the height of the scrollpaneContainer is larger than 2880 pixels (mc height limit).

I can split the movieclips into two scrollpaneContainer clips but I am unsure how to set the source of the scrollpane to be two different movie clips at the same time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know, Movie Clips don't have a height limit, definitively not at 2880 pixels. That is the restriction for bitmaps. You should have no problems adding a MovieClip, unless you're caching it as a bitmap.

if you're not caching it as a bitmap, maybe provide some more info.

Comment: Looks as though you are correct with the limits. Limit I quoted was for document height.